# How to apply Eight-fold path[Aaryashtangika marga] to each virtue action as a Vipassana Meditation?

Tags: meditation, eightfold-path, wisdom, middle-way, empowerment

How to apply eight fold path to the wholesome act as meditation of three marks of existence (Pali: tilakkhaṇa) of all existence and beings, namely impermanence (aniccā), non-self (anattā) and unsatisfactoriness or suffering (dukkha)?

Comment: Please make the scope smaller, as written this question covers (almost) all of Buddhism.

Comment: @Sanath  You might enjoy this essay by Ṭhānissaro Bhikkhu entitled "First Things First". It provides a good understanding of how the three marks of existence were originally intended to be understood and applied in dhamma practice.  https://www.dhammatalks.org/books/FirstThingsFirst/Section0007.html

Comment: Thank you Deane it also helpful one to learn first thing first.  I really wanted to know to achieve this understanding we need to follow the eightfold path. It should be practice in daily da today life activities.  I wanted to know how to apply eight fold path in meditaion and other activities.

Comment: THe question isnt asking what is the Noble eightfold path. It is asking "how to apply" and that also in the context of Vipassana Meditation. Thus, there are 2 differences and therefore not a du0plicate question.